# How to pass arguments correctly to syscall (git)?

Tags: go, arguments, system-calls

I am trying to clone a git repository by calling git via `syscall`. (I know there is [git2go](https://github.com/libgit2/git2go) but that's not what I want. I definitely want to do a `syscall`)

```
git, lookErr := exec.LookPath("git")

if lookErr != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s\n", lookErr)
    os.Exit(126)
}

args := []string{"clone", "http://github.com/some/repo.git"}

var env = os.Environ()

execErr := syscall.Exec(git, args, env)

if execErr != nil {
  panic(execErr)
}
```

So what I want to execute is `git clone http://github.com/some/repo.git` and executing this manually works just fine. But when I run it in go like in the code snippet above, git fails with this:

> git: 'http://github.com/some/repo.git' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Why would git interpret the 2nd argument as another command? It is supposed to be the remote `<repo>` URL, `git clone [options] [--] <repo> [<dir>]`.

How do I pass the arguments correctly so git has the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `argv` is usually a program's name, so just add it there:

```
args := []string{git, "clone", "http://github.com/some/repo.git"}
var env = os.Environ()
if err := syscall.Exec(git, args, env); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

See also: [`os.Args`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables) variable.

Comment: I see. It's a bit non-intuitive since the program name was already passed as first argument and this first argument was clearly used since the error message was from git. But looking at the [example](https://gobyexample.com/execing-processes) from where I was learning, I should have noticed that. I just would have never expected to pass the program name again as argument so I didn't pay attention to the values in the example. My bad. Thanks for clearing up.